# What tolerance to use for fit by hand

Tags: mechanical-engineering, tolerance

I am desigining an aluminium part that takes in Wixroyd 32300.W0003 plunger with stainless steel body. The hole in question is 3mm and I want to be able to push-fit plunger with my hand (ie not by using a press or another tool). Obviously I don't want the part to slide out easily. I am open to using a retaining compound to keep the part in place.

There isn't much load on the plunger or part, but there is vibration that could make the plunger work its way out if it is too loose.

The Wixroyd site is not clear about tolerances used for this part and it seems that the diameter could be +-0.1mm (!) by at the same time they suggest H7 tolerance on the hole.

I am unsure what would be the typical hole tolerance to allow fit by hand? I was originally thinking about H7 but it feels a bit too tight for hand fit.

I was thinking should I increase to eg H11 but I have no experience to guide me on how much tolerance in absolute terms (ie mm) is enough for fit by hand.

I was also thinking about using a 3.25mm hole (i.e. +0.25mm bigger) and a retaining compound like Loctite 628.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What tolerance shouold be good enough for fit-by-hand?
2. Would a +0.25mm with Loctite 628 retainer be a good approach or would you advise against this?

Comment: Ahh, but which hands? Braun Strowman or a 6 year old? I upset the foreman when I was an apprentice - a gudgeon pin was stuck in a piston that he could not remove. I pulled it straight out... He could not believe it so put the pin back in and then could not pull it out. Again i did. repeat twice more as he gets more and more upset.

Comment: What about a physical control like circlips in a groove?

Comment: Deeper hole with longer rod also increases in force as you go down and the mated area increases. 0.25mm oversized hole is excessive. Half that feels ultra sloppy already. Stick a rod into a micrometer and open it up by just 0.1mm and feel how sloppy it is. 
The hole being oversize by 5 tenths, 0.0005", or 0.0127mm will be plenty for a slip fit. Honestly it just not has to be undersized. Be aware the tightest slip fits cannot be inserted without a press since they require perfect perpendicularity. But if you want anti-vibration you need an undersized hole. So your goals are conflicting.

Comment: Thank you! @DKNguyen this is very helpful - I will just go with H7 as this should fit the 0.01mm tolerance and slip fit.

Comment: @SolarMike - you are clearly a strong guy :) I didn't go for physical controls as I have very restrictive space/dimensional constraints (otherwise I would have used a threaded plunger). Good question though, I should have mentioned the dimensional constraints in the question!

Comment: @user234324 That's not a tolerance by the way. It's really that your ideal hole dimension is (nominal rod diameter + positive rod diameter tolerance tolerance + 0.01mm) and your tolerance is something like +0.02mm. If you just make your hole diameter to be your nominal shaft diameter + 0.01mm or +/- 0.01mm you could end up in trouble. You could *probably* specify the hole to be nominal rod diameter with a +0.02mm and be okay though. You don't want a +/- tolerance here.